# Updating a Gitlab repository using the git-rake command

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am looking at importing various public GitHub repositories into a private [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com) server.  [I found these instructions](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md) detailing how to import bare repositories into Gitlab via the command line using the `git-rake gitlab:import:repos` command.

What I would like to know is the proper way for keeping my local copy of the repository in Gitlab in sync with the repository on GitHub.  I will not be making any changes to the copy I have, I only want to retrieve  updates from the remote repository.

Can I perform a `git fetch` on the local bare repository and have Gitlab recognise it?  Would I have to run the `git-rake gitlab:import:repos` task whenever I retrieve new changes via `git fetch`?  Or is that unnecessary?

Or am I way off base and there's a better way to keep my local copy in sync with the remote copy?

Thanks.

<sup>Note: I am aware that a repository can be imported through the Gitlab web UI, but I do not see any options for keeping the repository in sync.</sup>

Comment: Use `git clone --mirror` as documented here: https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/

Comment: The issue isn't with making a mirror, the issue is getting updates from the original repository and having Gitlab recognise them properly.